# How to document actionlib interface / Best practice for messages from .action files

Tags: ros, actionlib, rosdoc, best-practices, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to document the action interface in [nao_driver](http://ros.org/wiki/nao_driver) which uses custom actions defined in [nao_msgs](http://ros.org/wiki/nao_msgs). However, the messages themselves are generated from the .action files and this does not seem to happen when the wiki documentation is built. As a result, the message links in the node documentation point to nonexistent pages and there are no actions visible at [nao_msgs](http://ros.org/wiki/nao_msgs) in the MsgSrvDoc macro block.  How should I document the interface? Is it considered "best practice" to check in the generated msgs from the .action files? I don't like the fact that this could cause a new checkin every time they are regenerated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12339/how-to-document-actionlib-interface-/-best-practice-for-messages-from-.action-files/) by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5904 on 2011-12-13

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. How should I document the interface?

See http://ros.org/wiki/move_base for the current 'best practice'.  It's not great, but all that's possible now w/o  someone writing a plugin for rosdoc to handle actions the same way we do with msg/srvs.

2. Is it considered "best practice" to check in the generated msgs from the .action files?

You should never check in generated files.

If you wanted to get very clever, you could run rosdoc on your package against a built tree and save the msg docs and link to those, but that's still not an ideal solution to #1.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-12-17**:
I meant to run rosdoc locally and uploading the html files to a server

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-12-16**:
Doesn't this mean that the msg files were checked in so rosdoc can generate the corresponding html?

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-12-16**:
Well I actually looked at move_base which caused my confusion ;) If you look at the action messages, all the links to message definitions (e.g. http://www.ros.org/doc/api/move_base_msgs/html/msg/MoveBaseActionGoal.html) are working.